# How can I play a video while Unity webgl is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

i'm building a webgl application with unity right now and i want, that while the website is loading the unity container i want to play a video. The problem is, that i want the video to be closed, when the game is loaded.
Thx in advance
levoxtrip

Comment: To do that, you have to load video and its functionality outside Unity. So in the index.html that gets created, add div container with a video link to play and disable it when Unity finally loads. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp